# Appengine vs Nodejs Costs for Analytics Application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Currently, I have architectured our current application using nodejs & mongodb. This was done assuming that the date write costs for appengine will become too expensive than hosting nodejs and mongodb.

I need help in identifying the differences in the costs for an application which will grow to hit lets say about 50 requests/second. Each request is logged in database. The entities are really simple (id, datetime, email_address). The data is not recycled/deleted.

1. Use nodejs hosting provider like nodejitsu (not sure how many drones would I need for such traffic). Mongohq for db hosting. Or anyone you can prefer to cut down costs.
2. Use appengine for the same model with builtin datastore
3. Use appengine with Google Cloud SQL

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it on AppFog and get up to 512 mb ram for free.

Regarding Nodejitsu - 50 requests per second should be ok on 1 drone.

Even a very small VPS with 128mb ram could handle this load as well.